# Concatenating in for loop

Tags: python

it's a loop to reverse a string entered by the user, it reads letters in reverse and put them into a sentence. the problem is that, for example user's input is hello, the comma(,) in the last line of the code makes the output to be o l l e h, but if there isnt a comma there, the output will have each letter in a line. and concatenate (+) doesnt work it gives an error. What do i do so that the output would be olleh instead of o l l e h?

```
phrase = raw_input("Enter a phrase to reverse: ")
end = (len(phrase))-1
for index in range (end,-1,-1):
    print phrase[index],
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a for-loop for this?  Because, if not, you can simply do this:  `phrase[::-1]`

Comment: @iCodez Whenever I see "for-loop" and "reverse a string" in a question, I always assume it's a homework assignment.  Same goes for "while-loop" or "palindrome".

Comment: @iCodez  It's probably because all the CS professors know C/C++ better, and are only teaching python as a "service" class, so they never bothered to learn idiomatic python.  They are probably just teaching it the way they would teach C++. That would also explain why we see so many questions using setters/getter in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate something, you have to have a string to concatenate to. In this case, you need a variable that is defined outside of the for loop so you can access it from within the for loop multiple times, like this:

```
phrase = raw_input("Enter a phrase to reverse: ")
end = (len(phrase))-1
mystr = ""
for index in range (end,-1,-1):
    mystr += phrase[index]
print mystr
```

Note that you can also simply reverse a string in Python doing this:

```
reversedstr = mystr[::-1]
```

This is technically string slicing, using the third operator to reverse through the string.

Another possibility would be

```
reversedstr = ''.join(reversed(mystr))
```

`reversed` returns a reversed iterator of the iterator you passed it, meaning that you have to transform it back into a string using `''.join`

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
string = ''
for i in range(end, -1, -1):
    string += phrase[i]

print string
```

However, an easier, cleaner way without the for loop is:

```
print phrase[::-1] # this prints the string in reverse
```

And also there is:

```
#As dougal pointed out below this is a better join
print ''.join(reversed(phrase))
#but this works too...
print ''.join(phrase[i] for i in range(end, -1, -1)) # joins letters in phrase together from back to front
```

Comment: A nicer way to do something about equivalent to your third method is `''.join(reversed(phrase))`. `phrase[::-1]` is still the best way, though.